# Parse Json array with EasyMapping (Swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I have to work with EasyMapping. It works pretty good when I parse dictionaries from Json. But now I have to parse just an array of objects, so I don't have any key path. I have Json:

```
[
    {
        "key1": "dee",
        "key2": 3232
    },
    {
        "key1": "deeweewregre",
        "key2": 5555
    }
]
```

So I created 2 custom classes. The first one is for element in array:

```
class TheEntry: EKObjectModel {
    var key1: String!
    var key2: Int!
}

extension TheEntry {
    override class func objectMapping() -> EKObjectMapping{
        let mapping = EKObjectMapping(objectClass: self)
        mapping.mapPropertiesFromArray(["key1", "key2"])
        return mapping
    }
}
```

And the other one for array itself:

```
class TheList: EKObjectModel {
    var entries: [TheEntry]!
}

extension TheList {
    override class func objectMapping() -> EKObjectMapping{
        let mapping = EKObjectMapping(objectClass: self)
        mapping.hasMany(TheEntry.self, forKeyPath: mapping.rootPath)
        return mapping
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. My app crash on mapping.rootPath. But I have no idea how else tell to work with root level of Json.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
mapping.hasMany(TheEntry.self, forKeyPath: "@self")
```